# The buttons not working when I use load() function in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

When I use the load() method,the buttons in the file that loaded don't work;

Code in main page;

`$("html").load("demo.php")`

Code in demo.php;

```
<button id="btn">Alert</button>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function(){
alert("Hello")
}
</script>
```

The button works fine when i only open the demo.php but doesn't work when i load it into another document.
Any solutions?

---

When I replaced the html selector with the body selector it worked

`$("body").load("demo.php")`

---

I found out something but still doesn't explain the reason.
When I use the Javascript inline then it will work in the main page like this;

```
<button onclick="alert('hello')" id="btn">Alert</button>
```

Comment: I suspect `.load()` will not load the `<script>` element due to protection. Consider https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try other element insted of html

```
$("another selector").load("demo.php")
```

Add another elemnt in to your first page and use that elemt to load demo.php

When you are loading the demo.php you are removing the jquery from your page thats why you are getting nothing

Try to create another elemnt as i mentioned above

$("div").load("demo.php")

Comment: Oh yes i missed it in the question but not in the demo.php document

Comment: Try this out. ```$("body").on("click","#btn",function(){alert("hello");});``` You should write this code in main file.

Answer (score 0):

> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

So when you call:

```
$("#buttons").load("demo.php");
```

This will execute the Script block. You may want to consider adjusting this block to ensure it can work with the DOM better. Consider the following.

```
<button id="btn">Alert</button>
<script>
$("#buttons").on("click", "#btn", function(e){
  alert("Hello")
});
</script>
```